# Container sizing in Bulma.io

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-position, bulma

I have started to learn Bulma. I want to minimize container's (grey area in the picture) size in x-axis so I can embed elements into.Couldn't find any related content in documents. Here is my source code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" it> 
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.css">
</head>
<body>
<section class="hero is-medium">

    <div class="hero-body has-background-danger">
        <nav class="navbar has-background-primary">
            <div class="container has-background-grey-light is-fluid ">
           </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the sample view of this code:
[image: grey area is the one that I want to minimize]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can wrap it in a `column` class and then adjust its size. (ex. `is-half`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" it> 
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.css">
</head>
<body>
<section class="hero is-medium">
    <div class="hero-body has-background-danger">
      <div class="columns is-centered">
       <div class="column is-half">
         <nav class="navbar has-background-primary">
            <div class="container has-background-grey-light is-fluid">
            </div>
         </nav>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I want it in center of hero body(pink area).It seems it just went to right side.

Comment: @KadirSusuz Updated my answer!